# Recover the getSelectedValue from addMouseListener

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

In listMarques.addMouseListener, I would like to get the `String` in selectedCategories. I have tried this in my class,

```
Private selectedCategories = null
```

but it's not working.

```
listCategories.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String selectedCategories = listMarques.getSelectedValue().toString();
                System.out.println(selectedCategories);
            }
        });

        listMarques.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String selectedMarques = listMarques.getSelectedValue().toString();

                if(selectedMarques  != null && selectedCategories != null)
                {


                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are listCategories and listMarques `JList`? If so, you shouldnt use a MouseListener to solve this. Instead, you should use a `ListSelectionListener`.

For better help, you should improve your question to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the member variable with your local variable.

Replace

```
String selectedCategories = listMarques.getSelectedValue().toString();
```

with

```
YourClassName.this.selectedCategories = listMarques.getSelectedValue().toString();
```

where `YourClassName` would be the name of the class in which you are holding the member `selectedCategories` as well as the above code.

Good luck.